# Chrome background image fixed re-draw issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-chrome

For a site I'm currently working on. I'm trying to give a background image a kind of parallax effect on the page. Basically I have a div which has a set height and I'm updating the background-image of the div as the user clicks on each rotator item. The background image is fixed to the top centre an it works absolutely fine when the page first loads. But if you scroll down slightly so part of the div is not visible and switch items in the rotator the background image only loads at a certain point of the div but soon as I scroll or touch any element in the inspector it fully loads.

Here is my mark-up in case I'm doing anything wrong, but It works fine in Firefox and IE7/8/9 but just not Chrome. Any help would be much appreciated.

```
.home .rotator
{
    height:450px;
    background: fixed center top no-repeat;
    background-size: 100% auto;
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

$(".home .rotator").css("background-image", "url('" + bgImg + "')");
```

If you need any further info please let me know.

Comment: Set up a jsfiddle demonstrating the problem.

Comment: Managed to resolve the issue in the end, Instead of 
background: fixed center top no-repeat; Removed the fixed and use background-attachment:fixed;

Comment: @johnw86, add your own solution as answer and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to resolve the issue in the end, instead of background: fixed center top no-repeat; Removed the fixed and use background-attachment:fixed;